# If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets of vectors in a vector space $V$, and if $\operatorname{span}X\subset\operatorname{span}Y$, then $X\subset Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

There is proof for “If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets of vectors in a vector space $V$, and if $X\subset Y$, then is $\operatorname{span}X\subset\operatorname{span}Y$?” But I need to prove it conversely that if $X$ and $Y$ are two sets of vectors in a vector space $V$, and if $\operatorname{span}X\subset\operatorname{span}Y$, then is  $X\subset Y$?"

Comment: It's not true. Consider $X=\{(1,1)\}$, $Y=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general. For instance, take $X=\{1\}$ and $Y=\{-1\}$ in $\mathbb R$. Then $\operatorname{span}X=\operatorname{span}Y(=\mathbb R)$, but $X\not\subset Y$ and $Y\not\subset X$.

Comment: Can you please give an example of when it is true? I mean in some cases when it is true.

Comment: Sure. For instance (still in $\mathbb R$), $\operatorname{span}\{1\}\subset\operatorname{span}\{1,-1\}$ and $\{1\}\subset\{1,-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be the poset of subsets of $V$ and $D$ be the poset of subspaces of $V$, both considered as categories. Then, taking the span is a functor from $C$ to $D$, and is left adjoint to the inclusion functor from $D$ to $C$.

The question is then equivalent to asking whether taking the span is a fully faithful functor. It cannot be, for the adjunction would then be an adjoint equivalence, but the inclusion functor is clearly not an equivalence because the empty set is not in the essential image.